# Robolectric: ClassCastException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, cordova, testing, gradle, robolectric

I'm attempting to get Robolectric 2.4 working with my Cordova Project in Android Studio 1.0.2 and when I run the test `./gradlew clean test` I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError cannot be cast to java.lang.RuntimeException
at org.robolectric.internal.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethodReflectively(ReflectionHelpers.java:68)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:115)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:268)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:122)
at de.dfki.telcoPortal.example.DeckardActivityRobolectricTest.setup(DeckardActivityRobolectricTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried different solutions but not luck. I don't know what I made wrong. Could anyone help me with this error?

My top-level build.gradle looks like:

```
  buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
           classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.+'
       }
    }

    allprojects {
       repositories {
          mavenCentral()
      }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'robolectric'

    android {
       packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile './src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['./src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        }
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildTypes {
    }


    }
    robolectric {
        include '**/*Test.class'
       }

   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0'
    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'ple`enter code here`xus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
   }

apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```

My Activity is:

```
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
       loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

and my basic Test is

```
@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class CordovaAppTest{

   private CordovaApp activity;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {

        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(CordovaApp.class)
                .create().get();
        assertTrue(activity != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassCastException: NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to RuntimeException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574165/classcastexception-noclassdeffounderror-cannot-be-cast-to-runtimeexception)

Comment: Also worth looking at this issue, mentioned in that question: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1385